# Recycling and assignment functions (`split<-`)

Tags: r, syntax, functional-programming

Can someone please explain me how this one line of R code works?

```
split(dat, f) <- lapply(split(dat, f), max)
```

I thought it is a just a recycling rule but really I can't understand it.

Data example :

```
dat <- c(1, 2, 3, 100, 200, 300)
f <- as.factor(c("a", "a", "b", "a", "b", "b"))
split(dat, f) <- lapply(split(dat, f), max)
dat
[1] 100 100 300 100 300 300
```

The code do what I want to do (assign the max by group) but the question is how this is done?

Comment: Look at `\`split<-.default\``.

Comment: another lovely kaboom moment from the R manual

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The split gives the values `dat[c(1,2,4)]` and `dat[c(3,5,6)]` from the vector.

The assignment is equivalent to `dat[c(1,2,4)] <- 100 ; dat[c(3,5,6)] <- 300` and this is where the recycling takes place.

**Edited**

As for what happens, and why a vector assignment results, see page 21 of the language definition manual (http://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/R-lang.pdf).  The call:

```
split(def, f) <- Z
```

Is interpreted as:

```
‘*tmp*‘ <- def
def <- "split<-"(‘*tmp*‘, f, value=Z)
rm(‘*tmp*‘)
```

Note that `split<-.default` returns the modified vector.

Comment: Thanks! I like this answer. Myabe you need to explain why we get a vector and not a list as result.

Answer (score 5):

Thanks to the comment , the answer is in `split<-.default`

Just to explain its behavior, here I call the  `split<-.default` with result of my call in the question

```
`split<-.default` <- function(dat, f,value = lapply(split(dat, f), max))
{
    ix <- split(seq_along(dat), f, drop = drop, ...)  ## the call of split here!!
    n <- length(value)
    j <- 0
    for (i in ix) {
        j <- j %% n + 1
        x[i] <- value[[j]]  ## here we assign the result of the first split
    }
    x
}
```