# Sequentially numbering within many row blocks of unequal length

Tags: r

My actual dataset is composed of repeated measurements for each `id`, where the number of measurements can vary across individuals. A simplified example is:

```
dat <- data.frame(id = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L))
dat
##    id
## 1   1
## 2   1
## 3   1
## 4   1
## 5   1
## 6   1
## 7   2
## 8   2
## 9   3
## 10  3
## 11  3
```

I am trying to sequentially number the `dat` rows by the `id` variable. The result should be:

```
dat
##    id s
## 1   1 1
## 2   1 2
## 3   1 3
## 4   1 4
## 5   1 5
## 6   1 6
## 7   2 1
## 8   2 2
## 9   3 1
## 10  3 2
## 11  3 3
```

How would you do that? I tried to select the last row of each `id` by using `duplicated()`, but this is probably not the way, since it works with the entire column.

Comment: This question seems pretty similar.  In fact, I see now that is where I got my answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8209015/observation-number-by-group

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Use `ave()`. The first item is the item you're going to apply the function to; the other items are your grouping variables, and `FUN` is the function you want to apply. See `?ave` for more details.

```
transform(dat, s = ave(id, id, FUN = seq_along))
#    id s
# 1   1 1
# 2   1 2
# 3   1 3
# 4   1 4
# 5   1 5
# 6   1 6
# 7   2 1
# 8   2 2
# 9   3 1
# 10  3 2
# 11  3 3
```

If you have a large dataset or are using the `data.table` package, you can make use of "`.N`" as follows:

```
library(data.table)
DT <- data.table(dat)
DT[, s := 1:.N, by = "id"]
## Or
## DT[, s := sequence(.N), id][]
```

Or, you can use `rowid`, like this:

```
library(data.table)
setDT(dat)[, s := rowid(id)][]
#     id s
#  1:  1 1
#  2:  1 2
#  3:  1 3
#  4:  1 4
#  5:  1 5
#  6:  1 6
#  7:  2 1
#  8:  2 2
#  9:  3 1
# 10:  3 2
# 11:  3 3
```

---

For completeness, here's the "tidyverse" approach:

```
library(tidyverse)
dat %>% 
  group_by(id) %>% 
  mutate(s = row_number(id))
## # A tibble: 11 x 2
## # Groups: id [3]
##       id     s
##    <int> <int>
##  1     1     1
##  2     1     2
##  3     1     3
##  4     1     4
##  5     1     5
##  6     1     6
##  7     2     1
##  8     2     2
##  9     3     1
## 10     3     2
## 11     3     3
```

Answer (score 3):

```
dat <- read.table(text = "
    id          
    1 
    1 
    1 
    1 
    1 
    1 
    2 
    2 
    3 
    3 
    3", 
header=TRUE)

data.frame(
    id = dat$id,
    s = sequence(rle(dat$id)$lengths) 
)
```

Gives:

```
   id s
1   1 1
2   1 2
3   1 3
4   1 4
5   1 5
6   1 6
7   2 1
8   2 2
9   3 1
10  3 2
11  3 3
```

Answer (score 1):

using `tapply` but not  elegant as `ave`

```
 cbind(dat$id,unlist(tapply(dat$id,dat$id,seq_along)))
  [,1] [,2]
11    1    1
12    1    2
13    1    3
14    1    4
15    1    5
16    1    6
21    2    1
22    2    2
31    3    1
32    3    2
33    3    3
```

Comment: If you look at the function for `ave()`, you'll see that it contains [your question from earlier today](http://stackoverflow.com/q/14294052/1270695) ;)

Comment: @AnandaMahto thanks but I know that. You were faster than me with the ave,I change mine last minute.